# Highlight cell conditional on another cell being clicked

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, highlight

I have VBA code that works, but does not seem to be optimal. The code should change the colour of the text in the relevant cell in columns H & I when a cell in Column N is clicked.

For example, when cell N5 is clicked, the text in cells H5 and I5 should turn white. When it is unclicked, they return to their normal colour.

The code does not seem to be optimal because the change in column I lags behind that in column H.

I would like a way to make both change instantaneously.

(Bonus points if you can make the cells change colour AND turn into bold instaneously, with the constraint that like for colour, the bold disappears once the cell is unselected).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim r As Range

  Intersect(Columns("H"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Font.Color = vbBlack
  Set r = Intersect(Range("N:N"), Target)
  If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Cells(r.Row, "H").Font.Color = vbWhite

  Intersect(Columns("I"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Font.Color = vbBlack
  Set r = Intersect(Range("N:N"), Target)
  If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Cells(r.Row, "I").Font.Color = vbWhite

End Sub
```

Please note, this is my first time writing VBA, hence any amateurismes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to address each column separately...

EDIT: added bold and multiple cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, c As Range

    Set r = Intersect(Me.Range("N:N"), Target)
    '? what to do if user selects multiple cells ?
    'E.g. - exit if user has >100 cells selected (possibly whole column)
    If r Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.CountLarge > 100 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    HighlightIt Application.Intersect(Me.Range("H:I"), Me.UsedRange), False

    For Each c In r.Cells
        HighlightIt Me.Cells(c.Row, "H").Resize(1, 2)
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

'utility sub for highlighting/unhighlighting
Sub HighlightIt(rng As Range, Optional hilite As Boolean = True)
    With rng
        .Font.Color = IIf(hilite, vbWhite, vbBlack)
        .Font.Bold = hilite
    End With
End Sub
```

Always worth thinking about what should happen if the user selects multiple cells (or even a whole column).  Handling this robustly is sometimes  a challenge, depending on what you want to happen when they do that.

Comment: Wow had never heard of `.CountLarge` before, pretty neat https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-countlarge-property-excel

Comment: Precisely what I asked for. Many thanks. Two follow up questions: Am I correct that you did not address the bold issue that I mentioned at the end (absolutely no problem, if not)? And secondly, I like how you made it robust to multiple cells, but is it possible to expand the functionality over multiple cells? In any case, my question has been substantially answered, so I'll accept your answer. Many thanks!

Comment: See my edits - the font color/bold is factored out into a separate sub