# Conditional highlighting: How to optimise?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, conditional-statements, highlight

I have code which achieves exactly what I want. The basis of my code comes from the generous help of Tim Williams in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846059/6065710). Building on his help, I have added slightly to the functionality (larger font size, and returning formatting to original if nothing in the column is selected), and extended the code across several columns, as shown in the code.

The problem is my spreadsheet is now intolerably slow. Is there a way to speed things up?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, c As Range

    'Set target for all columns that have this functionality
    Set r = Intersect(Me.Range("N:Q"), Target)

    'The functionality is repeated for several columns and is identical each time (except for N which maps to two columns)

    'Column N maps to columns H & I
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing Then

    If r Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.CountLarge > 960 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        HighlightIt Application.Intersect(Me.Range("H:I"), Me.UsedRange), False
        For Each c In r.Cells
            HighlightIt Me.Cells(c.Row, "H").Resize(1, 2)
        Next c

    Else
         With Application.Intersect(Me.Range("H:I"), Me.UsedRange)
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
            .Font.Size = 14

          End With
    End If

    'Column O maps to columns J
     If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("O:O")) Is Nothing Then

    If r Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.CountLarge > 960 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        HighlightIt Application.Intersect(Me.Range("J:J"), Me.UsedRange), False
        For Each c In r.Cells
            HighlightIt Me.Cells(c.Row, "J")
        Next c


    Else
         With Application.Intersect(Me.Range("J:J"), Me.UsedRange)
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
            .Font.Size = 14

          End With
    End If


   'Column P maps to columns K
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("P:P")) Is Nothing Then

    If r Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.CountLarge > 960 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        HighlightIt Application.Intersect(Me.Range("K:K"), Me.UsedRange), False
        For Each c In r.Cells
            HighlightIt Me.Cells(c.Row, "K")
        Next c

    Else
         With Application.Intersect(Me.Range("K:K"), Me.UsedRange)
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
            .Font.Size = 14

          End With
    End If

    'Column Q maps to columns L
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Q:Q")) Is Nothing Then

    If r Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.CountLarge > 960 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        HighlightIt Application.Intersect(Me.Range("L:L"), Me.UsedRange), False
        For Each c In r.Cells
            HighlightIt Me.Cells(c.Row, "L")
        Next c

       Else
         With Application.Intersect(Me.Range("L:L"), Me.UsedRange)
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
            .Font.Size = 14

          End With
    End If

End Sub

'utility sub for highlighting/unhighlighting
Sub HighlightIt(rng As Range, Optional hilite As Boolean = True)
    With rng
        .Font.Color = IIf(hilite, vbWhite, vbBlack)
        .Font.Bold = hilite
        .Font.Size = IIf(hilite, 20, 14)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This would be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  SO is for problems with the code, Code Review is for how can you improve the code.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darren Bartrup is right. Code Review is an excellent site to obtain help on making your code more efficient.

I'm providing an answer as I'm not sure you've quite got the spirit of Tim Williams' answer. As well as not needing to iterate the cells, you should also be able to do without identical code for each tested column. You can do this by creating some form of selected column to highlight column map. Below is skeleton code to get you started.

The code you've supplied shouldn't be as slow as you are describing, so I wonder if you're handling other events (or there's more code in your `_Select` event). If there is, then make sure you include it in your question on Code Review or here.

```
Option Explicit

Private mColumnMap As Collection
Private mOldRange As Range
Private mOldCellColour As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim mappedRange As Range
    Dim mappedCells As Range

    'Define the column map.
    If mColumnMap Is Nothing Then
        Set mColumnMap = New Collection

        mColumnMap.Add Me.Range("H:I"), "14" 'N
        mColumnMap.Add Me.Range("J:J"), "15" 'O
        mColumnMap.Add Me.Range("K:K"), "16" 'P
        mColumnMap.Add Me.Range("L:L"), "17" 'Q
    End If

    'If there is a highlighted range, change it back.
    If Not mOldRange Is Nothing Then
        With mOldRange
            .Interior.Color = mOldCellColour
            .Font.Bold = False
        End With
        Set mOldRange = Nothing
    End If

    'Ignore any selections that are more than one column.
    If Target.Columns.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    'Ignore any selections outside of a specified range.
    'Note: I've just used the 'UsedRange'.
    If Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Acquire the appropriate column map.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mappedRange = mColumnMap(CStr(Target.Column))
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Exit if not a target column.
    If mappedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Define the cells to be changed.
    Set mappedCells = Intersect(mappedRange, Target.EntireRow)

    'Store the original values.
    Set mOldRange = mappedCells
    mOldCellColour = mappedCells(1).Interior.Color

    'Change the values.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With mappedCells
        .Interior.Color = vbWhite
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately your skeleton code is beyond my current VBA skills.For example, from my point of view it makes no sense to use an if statement on a variable before it's defined (see mColumnMap). I had a decent grasp of the code I cobbled together based on the previous answer, but yours seems a bridge too far. I know SO is not a code writing platform, so I don't expect you to write the code for me, instead I think I'll just try to streamline the functionality of my code to try reduce the delay. Really appreciate your contribution though and I'm sure better VBArs will benefit in the future!

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said: `mColumnMap` is defined at module-level, ie at the top of the page. I'll add this as an edit. You should be fine to just paste this code and run with it, but if you have something that already works then, yes, go with that. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Brilliant! Not only faster, but clearer too. Really appreciate you helping me out, it's exciting to see the finished product! Thanks again.